# How do I add custom headers to CloudFoundry error pages?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an application that I'm deploying on a private CloudFoundry instance, using the Ruby buildpack. Sometimes, an in-bound request causes my application to crash and the container to restart. At this point, the user is served an error page, saying something like `Error 502 - container was unable to service your request`, or something. This is not an error served by my app, but by the infrastructure, so I don't have any control over it.

My app is designed to be run as part of a dashboard/kiosk that refreshes periodically, and adds a `Refresh` header to every successful request. The refresh time is dynamic and not always the same value (it may be anything from 5 mins to 0 seconds), and that's why I don't use a browser refresh extension.

When I hit the error page, there is no `Refresh` header so the page just sits there forever. How can I get CloudFoundry to add a `Refresh` header to the error page? I'd be content with that value being some static value set in my `manifest.yml`, but I can't see any option to get it to do that.

Comment: Do you or have you tried scaling up your instance count to be greater than one?  My understanding is that if the app crashes and fails, GoRouter should retry as long as there are other app instances available.  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter#load-balancing

Comment: @DanielMikusa Hm, yes, I'm running two instances, and it doesn't seem to have an effect. It could be that it's causing them both to crash, I suppose.

Comment: That is possible.  If both instances went down, you'd get a 502.  If you run `cf events` you can see when the app has crashed and look to see if the times are close or overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify responses that are generated by the Gorouters. If you want to customize THOSE, you should consider, if you have the authority, to put something in your external load balancer that would watch for errors from the infrastructure (I believe all such errors have headers that start with `X-Cf-*` but I may be mistaken) and customize when they are received.